# jquery datepicker not accepting dateformat

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I have the following code in my view:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="date-from" name="date-from" value="" placeholder="Van" data-class="datepicker" />
```

I would like to retrieve the value of this field via AJAX for filtering.
The default format for input is mm/dd/yyyy (which i can't change either...)

So I tried getting the results in the format yyyy-mm-dd as i want them.

The following are my lines in javascript, they all return the exact input (mm/dd/yyyy)

```
alert($('#date-from').datepicker({ format: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val());
            alert($('#date-from').datepicker({ format: 'yyyy-mm-dd' }).val());
            alert($('#date-from').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val());
            alert($('#date-from').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd' }).val());
```

Comment: When you say 'the default format for input' does that mean you aren't using the datepicker to input the dates? It almost sounds like you are trying to use the datepicker to convert date formats, which isn't what that is meant to do. Could you expand a little more?

Comment: I am using the datepicker for users to select a date 'from' and date 'to'. I would like to compare the date picked by the user to the date in mysql table. When I do a alert($('#date-from').datepicker('getDate')); the returned value is Fri Sep 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a datepicker that outputs in `yyyy-mm-dd` Does that help?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(date) {
      alert(date);
    },
    dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use alt-format http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altFormat
. And then in your ajax call you can read value form hidden field that have date value in your desired format.

```js
$(function(){
    
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        altField: '#altdate',
        altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
    
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
Date Field : <input id="datepicker" type="text" /><br />
Alt Hidden Field : <input id="altdate" type="text" /><br />
<input id="thesubmit" type="button" value="Submit" />
```

Or you can use manually do that by splitting string on the basis of "-" and the reverse it

```js
$(function () {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
  });
  $("#datepicker").change(function () {
    var currentDate = $("#datepicker").val();
    console.log("Desired format : ",currentDate.split("-").reverse().join('-'));
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input id="datepicker" type="text">
```